# How to bullet NOT following object in unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

When i shoot my bullet it chases the enemy. I want to have an aiming system,
for example, the bullet should go to the enemy's position when it was first seen (not chasing object, just shoot to the first position the enemy was seen).
This is my code and it makes the bullet follow the enemy:

```
 void shoot() {
     GameObject bulletGO=(GameObject)  Instantiate(BulletPrefab, firepoint.position, firepoint.rotation);
     Bullet bullet = bulletGO.GetComponent<Bullet>();
     if (bullet != null) {
         bullet.Seek(target);
     }
```

and :

```
private Transform target;
public float speed = 5f;
public GameObject ImpactEffect;
public void Seek(Transform _target) {
    target = _target;
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {
    if (target == null)
    {
        Destroy(gameObject);
        return;
    }
    Vector3 dir = target.position - transform.position;
    float distancethisframe = speed * Time.deltaTime;
    if (dir.magnitude <= distancethisframe)
    {
        HitTarget();
        return;
    }

    transform.Translate(dir.normalized * distancethisframe, Space.World);
}
```

so any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

```
private Transform target;
//... 
public void Seek(Transform _target) {
target = _target;
}
//...
Vector3 dir = target.position - transform.position;
```

with

```
private Vector3 target;
//...
public void Seek(Transform _target) {
target = _target.position;
}
//...
Vector3 dir = target - transform.position;
```

That way you caluclate and copy existing target position in Seek and make bullet fly to that position, even if actual target move away. The code you had actually took current target position each time the Update was called.